# How to move one view controller to another view controller when we login with Twitter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am beginner in iOS and in my project I have given Twitter login facility for user and when we click login button we get Twitter login page as shown in the screen below.

After we login then user I click `AuthorizedApp` button which is there in Twitter login page.

Then I want to move another view controller(i.e ViewController1) for this i have written some code but using that code i cant move one viewController to another view controller.

Note: my main intention is when I click "AuthorizedApp" button, I want move ViewController to ViewController1

### My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController ()<FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"yyp5D4Elbo4fBAdnbnOZDaPRt" andSecret:@"WwIfOHvw8j0rIlLPtBQiPZ5r1dl44X4Lh8H6rKY5gLb1m4YM72"];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];

    //google plus login button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(loginOAuth)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(170, 200, 40, 40);

    CALayer * d = [button layer];
    [d setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [d setCornerRadius:20];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)loginOAuth {

    UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");

        NSLog(@"User name ---->>>%@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername);
        NSLog(@"User id ------> %@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID);

        ViewController1 *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        [dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should make a segue connection between your view controllers and give a identifier to the segue. After that you can use performSegueWithIdentifier method with your segue identifier name. In your case;

```
- (void)loginOAuth {

    UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");

        NSLog(@"User name ---->>>%@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername);
        NSLog(@"User id ------> %@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID);

// These codes work on background thread you should move them to the main thread
        /*ViewController1 *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        [dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];*/
    }];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierYouMustChange" sender:self]; // or sender nil
}
```

If performSegueWithIdentifier method does not solve your problem we can try to move your codes to the main thread.

Comment: no it's not working and my main requirement is when i click authorized app button i want display user details and then move another view controller